# How to specify scope for window in AngularUI Bootstrap modal?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create reusable confirm dialog using AngularUI Bootstrap modal, where "ok" / "cancel" buttons are in a custom `window` template. The issue is that while I can provide a scope for modal content, it's not available inside `window` template, so that I can't really call custom function when "ok" button is clicked.

Here's the code I've got currently:

```html
<a href="" fl-confirm-modal fl-confirm-modal-action="delete(training)" fl-confirm-modal-template="delete">Delete</a>
```

The directive has an isolated scope, which has `confirm` method that calls action passed to the directive (`fl-confirm-modal-action`) and closes the modal. The issue is that calling `confirm()` works fine inside modal content template, but doesn't work in modal window.

EDIT:

Here's a snippet from the directive:

```coffeescript
.directive "flConfirmModal",
($modal) ->
  restrict: "A"
  scope:
    action: "&flConfirmModalAction"
    template:  "@flConfirmModalTemplate"

  link: ($scope, $element, $attrs) ->
    $scope.confirm = ->
      $scope.modalInstance.close()
      $scope.action()

    $element.on "click", ->
      $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open
        scope: $scope
        windowTemplateUrl: "window_confirm.html"
        templateUrl: template
```

In `window_confirm.html` template there's a button with `ng-click="confirm()"` that is supposed to call `confirm` method defined the directive, but its scope is not available there.

Is there some workaround except moving "ok"/"cancel" from layout to each content template?

Comment: You're missing a lot of code here :-)

Comment: I've solved it for now by using the default `window.html` template and creating a separate layout template with ok/cancel buttons. User provides name of the template with content and I'm fetching both layout and content templates using `$http.get`, insert content template into layout template and pass the result as `template` parameter to `$modal.open`. This works fine and the only issue (though quite annoying) is that because I'm calling `$http.get`, the whole thing returns a promise that resolves to `modalInstance` instead of `modalInstance` directly.